# Help to conceive a name

Tags: terminology, ideals, lattice-orders, filters

*Filter* $F$ is defined by the formula $$A\cap B\in F \Leftrightarrow A\in F\wedge B\in F.$$

*Ideal* $F$ is defined by the formula $$A\cup B\in F \Leftrightarrow A\in F\wedge B\in F.$$

In my book I define *free star* $F$ by the formula $$A\cup B\in F \Leftrightarrow A\in F\vee B\in F.$$

The last thing is $$A\cap B\in F \Leftrightarrow A\in F\vee B\in F,$$
it is yet unnamed. Please help to conceive a name for the $F$ from the last formula.

Remark: There exists "natural" bijections between every two of the above defined four kinds of objects. They are essentially the same, that is.

Comment: A special case of a set conforming to the fourth formula is $F = \{A\in\mathscr{P}U \,|\, A\nsupseteq P\}$ for a set $U$ and its subset $P$.

Comment: May I name it "restriction"?

Comment: Or maybe name it "confinement"? (but now I like "restriction" more)

Comment: Or maybe name it "restraint"?

Comment: Hm, maybe I will stop at naming it "selector". This word is pretty much similar to the word "filter" in its informal meaning

Comment: Or even "mixer" as an opposite for "filter"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider **co-ideal**.

This may be helpful in remembering the main property of this new item.

What I mean is that $F$ is ideal means $$\forall A,B : A \cup B \in F \equiv A \in F \land B \in F$$ and the dual of $\cup$ is $\cap$, and the dual of $\land$ is $\vee$, so `dualising' the formula for ideal yields the formula
$$\forall A,B : A \cap B \in F \equiv A \in F \lor B \in F$$
which means $F$ is ``co-ideal'' :D

Hope that helps!